# Roku Error -3 (An unexpected ... (but not server timeout or HTTP error) has been detected.)

Tags: video, streaming, http-live-streaming, roku

*NOTE: Had to remove the word "problem" from the title due to community rules*

I am pulling an HLS stream into my Roku app with the following:

```
videoContent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
videoContent.url = m.top.extra
videoContent.title = "My Stream"
videoContent.streamformat = "hls"

videoContent.SubtitleConfig = {ShowSubtitle:1, TrackName:"eia608/1"}

m.video = m.top.findNode("videoplayer")
m.video.content = videoContent
m.video.enableUI = true
m.video.enableTrickPlay = false
m.video.control = "play"
m.video.setFocus(true)
```

Everything plays fine for awhile, but the feed stops at what appears to be random times. Sometimes it stops after 2 minutes, and sometimes it stops after several hours. I captured the video state and error:

```
 m.video.ObserveField("state", "changestate")
```

and

```
sub changestate()
    print m.video.state
    if (m.video.state = "error") then
        print "ERROR " + Str(m.video.errorCode) + " (" + m.video.errorMsg + ")"
    end if
end sub
```

When it stops, I get the following output in the console:

`ERROR -3 (An unexpected problem (but not server timeout or HTTP error) has been detected.)`

Does anyone know what this means? I see that others have had this issue, and they've posted about it, but it seems no answers have been posted online yet (that I'm able to find, anyway).

**DEVICE INFO:**

> Roku 4 (4400)
>
> Firmware **7.6.0.4120** and **7.7.0.4094**

Comment: Roku uses curl internally. -3 represent the curl error code 3: CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT - The URL was not properly formatted.

Comment: @brybott I don't think that's correct based on these https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roVideoPlayerEvent not matching those https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html